How to stop DataScannerViewController from converting barcode into EAN-13 format
I can successfully scan barcode numbers, but the scanner keeps converting them into EAN-13 format (by adding additional digits) but I just want the original barcode number. I've experimented with various barcode data types (such as .upce, .ean13, etc.), but only .ean13 seems to work for food products.
Example: Seaweed Barcode
Expected: "7441005955"
Input: "7441005955" (captured from camera)
Output: "0074410059552"
let viewController = DataScannerViewController(
    recognizedDataTypes: [.barcode()],
    qualityLevel: .accurate,
    recognizesMultipleItems: false,
    isHighFrameRateTrackingEnabled: false,
    isHighlightingEnabled: true)

func dataScanner(_ dataScanner: DataScannerViewController, didAdd addedItems: [RecognizedItem], allItems: [RecognizedItem]) {
    guard let item = addedItems.first else { return }
    
    if case .barcode(let barcode) = item {
        Task {
            guard var barcodeID = barcode.payloadStringValue,
                  let food = try? await foodService.getFoods(query: barcodeID).first
            else { return }
            // Handle barcode id
        }
    }
}



Product barcodes are typically either EAN13 (13 digits) or UPC-A (12 digits). A UPC-A has 10 main digits and 2 smaller digits, 1 on either end. Older ISBN numbers were 10 digits but that was for books. A UPC-A is easily converted to EAN13 by adding a leading 0. Are you sure you really have a 10-digit barcode and not a UPC-A (10 main + 2 small digits)?

Yea the barcode only has 10 digits with no 2 smaller digits, the item is called Shirakiku Furikake Nori Komi.
